# body background color not showing?

Tags: html, css

I just have a simple .shtml page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link href="Stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="Stylesheets/glicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
            Codepixl
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--#include file="nav.html"-->
         asdsd
        <div id="Scripts">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <script src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script> <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <script src="scripts/typed.js"></script> <script src="//codepixl.net/scripts/secret.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the stylesheet:

```
body{
    background-color: #32CD32;
}
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -115px;
  margin-left: -115px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

But the background color isn't showing up? I've tried using html,body{} and using a doctype but nothing works! What's happening?

**EDIT:** I removed bootstrap and it started working... Also here's the page: http://codepixl.net/indesx.shtml

**EDIT:**I just had to put the bootstrap before my stylesheet -_-

Comment: Check the network tab to make sure `Stylesheets/main.css` is getting loaded. Check the style inspector to make sure `background-color` is not being overridden. You might want to include your stylesheet **after** bootstrap.

Comment: Don't load your external script files within divs. That's not necessary, It should either go before the closing body tag or in the head section.

Comment: Seems to work as a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x41ry4t9/

Comment: try background: #32CD32; also I don't know if this changes anything but put a space between the word "body" and the opening brace "{"  and try to put a height AND width property

Comment: What happens when you apply inline style to body?

Comment: for me the problem was rgb. have to use hex apparently.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Had to include bootstrap before mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment your Bootstrap include and see if the body is applied.  You should try to test with the minimal amount of code first and then add in things.

If that doesn't work, you can use an inspector in Firefox or Chrome to see what CSS effects are applied.

You also may want to use the network inspector in Chrome to determine if your stylesheet is actually even getting downloaded or if the link is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I removed bootsrap and it started working... Here it is   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: If my solution solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer. :)  Also, I'm not sure if you have a second question or not?  The bootstrap reference is most likely defining a background color already.  All you need to do is change the order of your imports so that the bootstrap is the FIRST file imported, and then your CSS file will override anything defined in the bootstrap file that you explicitly specify.

Comment: The inspector suggestion is very useful, it helped me majorly.

Answer (score 18):

Override style from Bootstrap by adding `!important``

```
body{
    background-color: #32CD32 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

This worked for me. Without setting the height in html, the background-color property of body wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Although it wasn't the OP's issue, it was the issue I came searching for, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your body has a height of 0px. Add `height:100%` to your body styles and see if that works.

Comment: Try display:inline-block

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    <body BGCOLOR=#E8FFE8>
```

this sets the html  tag to a mint-y green

Answer (score -1):

You're using the bootstrap when this problem will be occur....

Avoid this problem to user !important keyword in css....

(Example):-

body{
background-color : #333 !important;
}`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.